# Sum of elements stored inside a tuple

Tags: python, python-2.7

Given a tuple containing a bunch of integer elements, how can one find the sum of all the elements?

For example, if I have a list of tuples:

```
li = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

How can I get something like this:

```
[3, 4, 5]
```

where 3, 4 and 5 is the total sum of each of the three tuples respectively?

Comment: How would you approach this? Is there any code you can show us that shows us *your* attempt?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) function like this

```
>>> li = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>> map(sum, li)
[3, 4, 5]
```

Alternatively you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), like this

```
>>> [sum(tup) for tup in li]
[3, 4, 5]
```

**Note:** I personally prefer the list comprehension version, because [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function in Python 3.x will return an iterable `map` object, which needs to be explicitly converted to a list, like this `list(map(sum, li))`.

```
>>> li = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>> map(sum, li)
<map object at 0x7f3dc25bb0f0>
>>> type(map(sum, li))
<class 'map'>
>>> list(map(sum, li))
[3, 4, 5]
```

But list comprehension will give a list in both Python 2.x and Python 3.x.

Comment: This is the error I encounter when I use the 'map' and 'sum' function together: TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: @ManasChaturvedi Please edit the actual code you tried and the traceback will also help debug the problem.

Comment: I tried 2 pandas shapes (2 item tuples) to sum but error is

TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Answer (score 5):

You could use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).

```
>>> li = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
>>> [x+y for (x,y) in li]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 2):

Both solutions below will work.

```py
li = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
print([sum(i) for i in li])
```

or

```py
def sumtupleinlist(lst):
    return [sum(i) for i in lst]
li = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

To test the function, run :

```py
print(sumtupleinlist(li))
```

Answer (score 1):

For beginner:

1. Create result variable which type is list.
2. Iterate every item from the give list by `for` loop.
3. As every item is tuple so again iterate item from the step 2 and set sum of item to 0.
4. Add sum.
5. Append sum to result variable.

Demo:

```
>>> li = [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]   # Given Input
>>> result = []                     # Step 1
>>> for i in li:                    # Step 2
...     tmp_sum = 0                 # Step 3  
...     for j in i:                 # Step 3
...         tmp_sum += j            # Step 4 
...     result.append(tmp_sum)      # Step 5 
... 
>>> print result
[3, 4, 5]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
ls= [(1,2), (3,4)]
finallist = []
for tuple in ls:
     listt = list(tuple)
     summ = 0
     for m in listt:
         summ+=m
     finallist.append(summ)
print(finallist) #[3,7]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

make a list having tuples -

```
tup = [(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)]

for (a,b) in tup:
    print(a+b)
```

This will give you -

```
3
7
11
```