# python serial data - incoming data according to previous line result

Tags: python

I receive data from serial (pyserial) line by line.

Is it possible to put a condition for each new incoming line according to the previous line result ? exemple :

```
data3 == int(incoming_data_serial) + int(data2)
```

This is my current code I am editing with a previous answer deleted by its author. It works fine. It gives result like this :

```
[63, 0]
[64, 63]
[64, 64]
[63, 64]
[63, 63]
etc...
```

which is promising. But still I need to know how to incorporate an operator (substract for exemple) between those datas. 
Exemple : instead of [64, 63] I would like to get only one data of 64 - 63 meaning 1 !

This is my code :

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 9600, timeout=0.1)

class _share:

def __init__(self):
    self.last_val = [0 for i in range(2)]

def calculate(self, val):
    #prepare data, convert
    self.last_data = val
    self.last_val = [self.last_data] + self.last_val[:-1]
    print((self.last_val))
    return self.last_val

share = _share()

def sensors(theimput):

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            ser.flushInput()
            sensor_reception = ser.readline()
            sensor_reception_split = sensor_reception.split()
            #data_sensor_milli = int(receptionsplit[3])
            data_sensor_pho_1 = int(sensor_reception_split[2])
            #data_sensor_tem_1 = int(receptionsplit[1])
            #data_sensor_hum_1 = int(receptionsplit[0])
            return str(share.calculate(data_sensor_pho_1))
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(0.1)

f = open('da.txt', 'ab')

while 1:
    arduino_sensor = sensors('1')
    f.write(arduino_sensor)
    f.close()
    f = open('da.txt', 'ab')
```

Comment: Where is the condition in your example?...but generally speaking, yes; you can do that

Comment: condition could be : "each time there s an  incoming data then recalculate the value of this data by adding it to the previous line result" ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The solution !

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import serial
import time
import operator

ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyS1', 9600, timeout=0.1)

class _share:

def __init__(self):
    self.last_val = [0 for i in range(2)]

def calculate(self, val):
    #prepare data, convert
    self.last_data = val
    self.last_val = [self.last_data] + self.last_val[:-1]
    b = reduce(operator.__sub__, self.last_val)
    print((b))
    return b

share = _share()

def sensors(theimput):

    while True:
        try:
            time.sleep(0.01)
            ser.flushInput()
            sensor_reception = ser.readline()
            sensor_reception_split = sensor_reception.split()
            #data_sensor_milli = int(receptionsplit[3])
            data_sensor_pho_1 = int(sensor_reception_split[2])
            #data_sensor_tem_1 = int(receptionsplit[1])
            #data_sensor_hum_1 = int(receptionsplit[0])
            return str(share.calculate(data_sensor_pho_1))
        except:
            pass
        time.sleep(0.1)

f = open('da.txt', 'ab')

while 1:
    arduino_sensor = sensors('1')
    f.write(arduino_sensor)
    f.close()
    f = open('da.txt', 'ab')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#ser is the serial object
#data is the variable u want to update

def sensors(last_data):
    temp = []
    while True:
        c = ser.read()
        if not c:
            time.sleep(0.1)
            continue
        if c == '\n' or c == '\r':
            break
        temp.append(c)
    temp = ''.join(temp)
    print('Raw readings:', temp)
    new_data = [int(d) for d in temp.strip().split())]  
    data = [a+b for a, b in zip(last_data, new_data)]
    print('Last data: ', last_data)
    print('New data:', new_data)
    print('Current sum:', data)
    last_data = [i for i in new_data]
    return data, last_data

last_data = [0] * 4
f = open('da.txt', 'a')

while True:
    try:
        sensor_data, last_data = sensors(last_data)
        #last_data = [i for i in last_data]   #uncomment this if the code doesnt work as is
        f.write(sensor_data.__str__() + '\n')
    except:
        f.close()
```

This code assumes you want to add the last received line of sensor data to the current line of sensor data. This is NOT a running sum.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I tried but I get this message  : new_data = int.from_bytes(ser.read(), byteorder='big')
AttributeError: type object 'int' has no attribute 'from_bytes'

Comment: @pythonrocks I assume you're using Python 2? Find out the type of data returned by `ser.read()`; if its `str`, then use `int()` to cast it instead. I will edit my code to read a line before converting the data

Comment: @ TisteAndii : How would u incorporate your code into the one i edited ?

Comment: @pythonrocks What type of data are you receiving? Strings? Or bytes? Show me what a line looks like

Comment: @ TisteAndii :I receive strings. The ser.readline() is like : "30 20 126 5026" (humidity, temperature, photocell, and milliseconds) but I split it in order to isolate datas. Then I get '126' only (for the photocell). This value is made via int() so that i can work with math operators on it.

Comment: @ TisteAndii : nothing appears on interpreter. On file : First line is : [0, 0, 32, 33427] and then I get this : [ ] on each following lines.

Comment: @pythonrocks I've edited the code. Edit your post so I can see your code.

Comment: Andii :  I have edited my post trying to insert your code. But doesn't work : same than before. Getting : ('Last data: ', [33, 20, 25, 4128])
('New data:', [])
('Current sum:', [])

Comment: What version of python are you using? Are the results you showed me, the WHOLE result? A picture of the exact results on screen and in the file would be nice.

Comment: Version is 2.7.1 . This is part of the result (since input datas never stop coming in) and here is the screenshot : [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/6HfpYQq.png)

Comment: @pythonrocks ok...show me the first few results not the ones at the end, so I can track exactly what happened. The problem may have to do with Also what is sending the data being received? An arduino? Let me reduce the code to simply get lines of sensor readings and if it works, then we'll continue from there. It looks like u're using python 3 though

Comment: I found the solution to the first problem. In fact, first thing to do is to "flush" the serial buffer. Now your program runs better. (I edit my code with the buffer flushing line). Current sum is ok. But still strange things happen. Here is the result (screenshot) : [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/pNvicMQ.png).

Comment: Try this and report results.

Comment: The flushing makes sense, but you may accidentally flush your sensor data. What if you flush first and then send some unique agreed byte to the sender to indicate you are ready to receive before calling the `sensors()` function?

Comment: No I tried. Only works fine within the loop and right after the time.sleep().

Comment: For it to work, you will need to make changes to the code embedded in the sender. But thats by the way, have you tried my edited code? You can also increase the baud so u dont have to wait so long for bytes

Comment: Your code does not work still. The same results than before. To find a solution I propose you to include your code inside this one [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/bjIVNCj.png) and to proceed as you said step by step... in order to debug little by little ?

Comment: If I were with your PC, I'd be able to find out the exact source of the problem with a few `print()`s, but since that isnt the case, you'll have to settle for trying a few things and posting the results here. The code works for the first 2 readings and after that it stops. I need to see the raw readings obtained in each function call, so I can pinpoint the problem, which could even be related to your sender if i'm right. You say you're using Python 2.7.1 yet the print functions you're using indicate you are using Python 3. Perhaps we should move this to the chat section.

Comment: Python 2.7 is installed but I m using ninja IDE editor which is python 3 "oriented". Thats why u might be confused on some prints (I correct them to avoid a blue underline ... ). /// Chating ? why not ! seems a good idea !

Comment: edited latest code... only remaining to find the solution how to add or substract the two datas inside the range...

Comment: Trying to put list(map(sum, self.last_val)) but does'nt work.

Comment: Can you summarise *exactly* what you want to do with the data you get over the serial connection?

Comment: I m sure solution is around there but I don't know how to implement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29471260/sum-of-elements-stored-inside-a-tuple

Comment: ok found the solution. See next answer. Thanks anyway for your help !